# Appending to existing array after alamofire response

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I have the following code which gets data from an API endpoint and formats this data into an object I can use inside my application. This object is then added to an array which can be accessed elsewhere in the application:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "x-api-version": "2",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request(jsonURLString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

    do {
        let establishmentsFromJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(EstablishmentsFromJSON.self, from: response.data!)

        if !(establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.isEmpty) {
            //print(establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingValue)

            establishment.hygieneRating = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingValue
            establishment.hygieneRatingKey = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingKey
            //convert to date object:
            establishment.hygieneRatingDate = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: establishmentsFromJSON.establishments[0].RatingDate)
            establishment.hygieneRatingPending = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.NewRatingPending
            establishment.localAuthorityName = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityName
            establishment.localAuthorityWebsite = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityWebSite
            establishment.localAuthorityEmail = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityEmailAddress

            // only show places I want to see
            self.establishments.append(establishment)
        }
    } catch {
        print("We have an error")
        print(error)
    }

}

// do UI stuff
self.showCount(self.establishments.count)

self.arView.displayItemsAroundCurrentLocation(currentLocation: currentPlace, establishments: self.establishments)
```

I am trying to append to an array inside my alamo request `self.establishments.append(establishment)`.

Adding `print(self.establishments.count)` immediately after the `append` allows me to see the that the elements are being added..
But if I try to access that array outside of the request, the elements don't exist/ don't get appended. Why is this?

I have a feeling it's down to the threads? I've attempted several examples of completion handlers like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43204314/8422218), and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38683361/8422218) but my array is still empty.

Adding

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    self.establishments.append(establishment)
}
```

inside my alamo request doesn't help resolve this issue.

I know I'm going wrong somewhere. Just can't quite work out where. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1fd8809e0013529106d936af61032cd

The `establishments` array gets created just below the class declaration.

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{
    @IBOutlet var headingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var refreshButton: CustomButton!

    var arView: ARViewController!
    var showsDebuggingLabels: Bool = false
    // location
    fileprivate let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
    var requestedItems: Bool = false
    // motion
    let debugHeading: Bool = true // make true to track heading
    let mmgr = CMMotionManager()

    var establishments = [Establishment]()
```

The API structure is as follows: http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Help/Api/GET-Establishments_name_address_longitude_latitude_maxDistanceLimit_businessTypeId_schemeTypeKey_ratingKey_ratingOperatorKey_localAuthorityId_countryId_sortOptionKey_pageNumber_pageSize

**EDIT 2:**

```
print(truncatedEstablishmentName[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: ""))
print(self.getPostalCode(place: place).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))
print(place.coordinate.latitude.description)
print(place.coordinate.longitude.description)
```

Returns:

```
Freeman
S1%202NG
53.3770956
-1.4682824
```

So the API request will be

```
let jsonURLString = "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments?address=S1%202NG&latitude=53.3770956&longitude=-1.4682824&maxDistanceLimit=0&name=Freeman"
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
                let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "x-api-version": "2",
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "content-type": "application/json"
                ]
                self.tryingWithCompletionHandler(jsonURLString: jsonURLString, headers: headers, establishment: establishment, completion: {
                    self.showCount(self.establishments.count)
                    print("place count: \(self.establishments.count)")
                    self.arView.displayItemsAroundCurrentLocation(currentLocation: currentPlace, establishments: self.establishments)
                })



            }
        }


    })
}

func tryingWithCompletionHandler(jsonURLString: String, headers: HTTPHeaders, establishment: Establishment, completion : ()->()) {

    Alamofire.request(jsonURLString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        do {
            let establishmentsFromJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(EstablishmentsFromJSON.self, from: response.data!)

            if !(establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.isEmpty) {
                //print(establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingValue)

                establishment.hygieneRating = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingValue
                establishment.hygieneRatingKey = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.RatingKey
                //convert to date object:
                establishment.hygieneRatingDate = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: establishmentsFromJSON.establishments[0].RatingDate)
                establishment.hygieneRatingPending = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.NewRatingPending
                establishment.localAuthorityName = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityName
                establishment.localAuthorityWebsite = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityWebSite
                establishment.localAuthorityEmail = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?.LocalAuthorityEmailAddress

                // only show places I want to see

                self.establishments.append(establishment)

            }
        } catch {
            print("We have an error")
            print(error)
        }

    }
    completion()
}
```

The above also gives me a count of 0. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: it is possible to share the complete code with API? then i will make more effective and simple code

Comment: Where does the `establishment` instance in the completion handler come from? By the way getting 6 times(!) the same object `establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first?` is unnecessarily expensive, rather than `if (establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.count > 0)` write `if let firstEstablishment = establishmentsFromJSON.establishments.first { ...` and **never ever** use `count > 0` to check if a collection type is empty. There is an `isEmpty` property.

Comment: @KhawarIslam Please see the gist in edit

Comment: @vadian Thank you very much for the suggestions! I have now amended my code. I was just trying to get my desired functionality to work initially, my next steps were to look at ways of refactoring my work. The `establishment` instance is declared a little higher (please see my gist in the edit). Thanks again!

Comment: @KhawarIslam http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Help/Api/GET-Establishments_name_address_longitude_latitude_maxDistanceLimit_businessTypeId_schemeTypeKey_ratingKey_ratingOperatorKey_localAuthorityId_countryId_sortOptionKey_pageNumber_pageSize this is the API result structure

Comment: Please share the parameters which you are passed, because i want to check the lat and long first.

Comment: @KhawarIslam Please see further edit

Comment: Man, problem is that service taking more parameter when i enter this four parameters. Cant return anything.

Comment: Have you tried the `jsonURLString` value at the bottom in Postman? It works for me. Just make sure the headers are set as laid out in the code above. This isn't the best API ever, I'll be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there and welcome to the world of async programming. Your feeling is right and also the linked solution should actually help you at least somehow. You did not show how you were using that completion closure solution.
However, your code has a few more issues. You iterate and request your items one-by-one, which could mean lots of unnecessary http requests and an equal number of UI updates that could interfere with each other. It would be better to have only one of that, and after its completion, you inform the UI as in your linked example.

If using some sort of batch API is impossible, consider using DispatchGroup (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) where you would wait until all requests have completed and then notify the UI only once.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. Please could you have a look at my Edit 3 as this was my implementation with completion handlers which I stated didn't achieve anything different. Could you please show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to call completion() *inside* the request-response (preferably at the end, after the do/catch statement), after the line where you append the establishment. However, this will trigger this completion for each request, of which you might have many ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I think I've solved the issue using DispatchGroup like you suggested.